# Handel screen from reactivelist to details screen

Tags: react-native, rendering, handle, native-base, reactivesearch

I have to secreen one listitem created by reactivelist in reactivesearch and second screen details item, how i can prees any item in list and display detiels for this item

Comment: Can you please add more details?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a clear understanding of react concept [Lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

And if you're using React-Navigation you can take help from RN APIs like this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/

Comment: Ok you know about reactivesearch https://opensource.appbase.io/reactivesearch/ and reactivelist component??

Comment: Mohamed Hussein, you are on old docs please visit the new docs.